What suggestions does the community have toward helping reopen this question?
Here is the closed question:



I would like to have feed that is not automated/robotic from the website that I can use to help edit this question so it can get reopened.
Because this is the main question that I would like to have answered.

“How does the computer with CPUs, with CPUs and GPUs, and now with the CPUs GPUs and the latest NPUs assess the Von-Neumann Bottleneck when it comes to AI applications?”

Any thoughts on how I could possibly get the answer for this question would be helpful. I think it is because I added to much research to the question or did I ask to many things in this one question.

https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Your question seems to be encouraging a discussion on the topic. Super User isn’t a discussion forum

Having a question that isn't a good fit HERE doesn't mean your question is a BAD question. Superuser is not about answering every question there is, but about answering specific sorts of questions. Your question is better served by a serious forum, lots of back and forth, input from many sources. That just isn't how things work here, and so, as much as your question doesn't fit here, here is also not the best place for your question.

Its too broad - even if its not a whole book's worth, its at least a research paper or thesis worth.
Topicality aside
As per our help pages

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

I also feel like this is more of a deep computer science question than a end user computing question.
If it was a 'simple' fix - you'd likely have comments, or editing. IMO, both in terms of how its written, and its subject material I don't feel like its a good fit for the site.
